# Do we need to provide same voltage for microcontroller I/O and oscillator?

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, crystal, microprocessor

I am using a [PIC32CZ8110CA90208-I8MX-SL3](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/PIC32CZ8110CA90208?_ga=2.228789209.452720271.1706684652-2052799221.1706684652) in my design. I am providing a supply of 1.8 V to VDDIO.

The oscillator used is a [DSC6011JI2B-012.0000](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DSC60xxB-Ultra-Small-Ultra-Low-Power-MEMS-Oscillator-DS20006133A.pdf).

Can I supply 3.3 V to oscillator VDD and 1.8 V to microcontroller VDDIO?

Will this cause any issues?

Is it necessary that oscillator supply should be equal to IO supply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ARM MCU and like most of them, it is no different.

The IO pins which are used for crystal are standard GPIO pins unless software decides to configure them for crystal use. The GPIO pins used by crystal are not even labeled "5V tolerant" so they can only handle same logic levels as VDDIO.

Feeding in a 3.3V clock may damage the MCU.

Yes, the clock should use VDDIO as supply.

Comment: The pins used for XTAL crystal generator are not standard GPIO pins, and an assumption that they can handle 3.3V GPIO amplitudes is overly optimistic.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I now double checked the data sheet, and the IO pins for crystal are standard GPIO pins PD1/PD0 capable of VDDIO voltages (not 3.3V because VDDIO is 1.8V and I never claimed otherwise) until they are configured as XIN/XOUT.  The data sheet also says it can work with an external clock signal instead of a crystal. So it can be assumed that if no special mention is made, the external clock can be a regular square wave at VDDIO amplitudes. Most ther MCUs are similar, it would be weird if this did not accept a square wave at VDDIO levels and left out what it requires then.

Comment: Could you please point me to specific page of the MSU datasheet with Vh and Vl requirement for XTAL pins?

Comment: @Ale..chenski They are GPIO pins until you turn on the crystal amplifier. You can choose to not turn the crystal amplifier on, and still use the PD1 pin as XIN for external clock, so then they are not crystal pins used for crystal. Datasheet has not listed Vh and Vl separately for PD1 pin when used as external clock or crystal input pin, just like it does not have them separately listed if you use any other GPIO pin for any other alternate function such as UART or SPI.

Comment: you are correct, section 18.6.2, page 214: "At reset, the XOSC is disabled, and the XIN/XOUT pins can be used as General Purpose I/O (GPIO) pins or by other peripherals in the system"

Answer (score 0):

If your VDDIO is 1.8V but an input signal is 3.3V, your design might have a problem to start correctly on power on. If your 3.3V power to the oscillator comes earlier than the 1.8V (which is likely), and the oscillator has a fast startup time, the 3.3V signal will charge the 1.8V rail up through ESD-protective clamp diodes (which are usually present on every input pin internally). The charged-up 1.8V rail might prevent your MCU from good internal power-on reset, and the MCU might fail to start. It all, of course, depends, but it is safer to avoid the overvoltage of IO pins.

I don't see any reason why you feed your oscillator with 3.3V, this model can handle 1.7V power supply. You also can delay the oscillator start using proper RC on enable pin. Or you can place a level shifter from 3.3 to 1.8V, it will cost only one MOSFET.

**CORRECTION**: The OP mentions "crystal oscillator", which is an active clock generator that forcibly drives clock signal to 0-VDD levels. The PIC32CZ CA80/CA90 Family shows XTAL IN and OUT pins for use with CRYSTALS resonators, passive devices. Although the datasheet does mention an ability to feed the MCU with EXTERNAL CLOCK (like from a "crystal oscillator") into XIN pin, it does not mention any max parameters for the XIN. Any assumptions regarding this pin needs to be taken very carefully. The [built-in XTAL circuitry](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/340274/117785) usually uses fairly low voltages and manages weak output power of the order of microWatts, and may use voltages in the range of 1-1.2V, much lower than the general IO pins. Some PIC32 MSU even had an Errata stating that they cannot use external clocks, see this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/253994/117785) Therefore even an input of 1.8V to XIN may provide improper duty cycle for internal clock distribution tree. You might need to consult with MCU manufacturer on how to apply external clock to this IC.

Comment: An one-FET level shifter for 12 MHz clock, why even bother trying that? Also these kind of ARM MCUs do have so called "5V tolerant" pins that don't have the clamp diodes to VDDIO, but the crystal pins are not 5V tolerant, but if they were, there would be no problem applying 3.3V signals to such IO pin even if MCU is unpowered for a generic ARM MCU like this (did not check this specific MCU). But otherwise yes, a 3.3V clock would try push VDDIO supply beyond. 1.8V towards 3V and it might do damage if onboard VDDIO must be limited to 1.8V.

Comment: @Justme, you seem to miss the point. The issue is not about damaging anything (a tiny crystal hardly can damage anything), but about voltage charge-up that might break the MCU power-on resets.

Comment: That is not crystal (as in piece on quartz you connect to a MCU directly) but an oscillator (as in it's a 3.3V output connected to an IO pin which can't handle more than VDDIO, and VDDIO is only 1.8V if even present at start-up). So it is wrong regardless of looking at power-up event or just powers being applied.

Comment: @Justme, the DSC60XXB has typical output of 1 mA. It is a tiny mems-based generator. Your fixation on possible GPIO damage is grossly unfounded.